# Ruby on rails wont change to mysql

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have just started using Ruby on rails and I have run into a very wierd problem. It seems like my rails app just wont use mysql as a database.

I managed to create my app with a mysql db but then when I tried to generate a scaffold it started to nag about me needing to install postgres which I thought was wierd but I did that and installed all the required libraries. Now I was able to create my scaffold but when I try to run rake db:migrate it tries to connect to a postgres database on my system.

Isn't this really wierd? Why would it bother me about pg when I said in my rails new command that I wanted to use mysql? And why wont it let me use mysql even though there is not a single reference to pg or postgres in my entire application?

I have tried reading a lot of tutorials and stuff but I can not seem to find what I have done wrong, but I really hope some of u guys can point me in the right direction!

UPDATE: From the connection output in db:create and db:migrate it seems like the server has cached some config from another project with the same name that I deleted a few days ago. I'm not able to find this cache, does it exist? If then where?

Commands I have run:

```
rails new MyApp -d mysql
rails generate scaffold name:string
rake db:migrate (results in connection timeout to the nonexistent pg db)
```

Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.1.1'
# Use mysql as the database for Active Record
gem 'mysql2'

# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer',  platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more:         https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc

# Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background.     Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
gem 'spring',        group: :development

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

# Use debugger
# gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]
```

database.yml:

```
# MySQL.  Versions 5.0+ are recommended.
#
# Install the MYSQL driver
#   gem install mysql2
#
# Ensure the MySQL gem is defined in your Gemfile
#   gem 'mysql2'
#
# And be sure to use new-style password hashing:
#   http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/old-client.html
#
default: &default
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: password
  socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

development:
  <<: *default
  database: rento_development

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  <<: *default
  database: rento_test

# As with config/secrets.yml, you never want to store sensitive information,
# like your database password, in your source code. If your source code is
# ever seen by anyone, they now have access to your database.
#
# Instead, provide the password as a unix environment variable when you boot
# the app. Read http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-a-database
# for a full rundown on how to provide these environment variables in a
# production deployment.
#
# On Heroku and other platform providers, you may have a full connection URL
# available as an environment variable. For example:
#
#   DATABASE_URL="mysql2://myuser:mypass@localhost/somedatabase"
#
# You can use this database configuration with:
#
#   production:
#     url: <%= ENV['DATABASE_URL'] %>
#
production:
  <<: *default
  database: rento
  username: rento
  password: <%= ENV['RENTO'] %>
```

System:

- Ubuntu 14.04 x64
- Rails 4.1.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow this was a silly error. Seems like I have a environment variable from a JAVA project I'm working in that is named DATABASE_URL. And I guess this is a standard that Rails uses. Changing the env fixes all my problems!

Answer (score 1):

Your adapter option on `database.yml` should be `mysql` instead of `mysql2`.

And you could run `rake db:create` before `rake db:migrate`, this will create the database for you before running the migrations.

Hope I could help.

Comment: Hmm that is wierd, why does rails generate it to mysql2 if it is supposed to be mysql?.. However, changing it does not fix the problem! It still tries to access a postgres db.

Comment: mysql2 is just the name of the gem. Maybe try to execute `bundle exec rake db:create`. The problem might be the gemset.

Comment: Same result again =/. Updated original post with some clues that I have found.